Spotify: Intermittent HTTPError 401 when searching for tracks
I have a script that searches for tracks using the spotify API everyhour. I have noticed that the script throws HTTPError 401 on some search requests. The script requests for new access token in every run. The following is how the authorization flow works:
def authorize():
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
    username = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_USERNAME')
    client_id = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    client_secret = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')
    redirect_uri = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI')
    token = SpotifyOAuth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, scope=scope, username=username)
    return token

The piece of code that throws the error:
    # Ensure the new song list does not have any old removed songs from previous playlist update
    for song in list_of_songs:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        result = spotifyObject.search(q=song, limit=5, offset=0, type='track', market='US')
        #print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=4, indent=4))
        if result['tracks']['total'] != 0:
            if result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'] not in remove_track_id:
                if result['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name'] in song:
                    result_list.append(result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])

This is what the error message looks like:
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/search with Params: {'q': 'GoGo Penguin Ascent', 'limit': 5, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'track', 'market': 'US'} returned 401 due to None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 271, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=GoGo+Penguin+Ascent&limit=5&offset=0&type=track&market=US

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/repos/Autoplaylist/autoplaylist.py", line 143, in <module>
    find_and_add_songs(playlist_id)
  File "/home/user/repos/Autoplaylist/autoplaylist.py", line 68, in find_and_add_songs
    result = spotifyObject.search(q=song, limit=5, offset=0, type='track', market='US')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 587, in search
    return self._get(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 323, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 293, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 401, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=GoGo+Penguin+Ascent&limit=5&offset=0&type=track&market=US:
 None, reason: None


I have tried limiting the rate of API calls and rotating API keys. None of these have worked so far.
Any input would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Have you confirmed your ip address is not getting restricted due to sending multiple API calls ?

The for loop does not exceed 20 iterations and has a time.sleep(0.5) to limit the rate. According to the Spotify documentation, it will receive a 429 error if the rate is exceeded but does not specify what the rate is exceeded.
Spotify API rate limits italic bold

401 typically means an "Unauthorized" error, make sure the token you’re using is valid.

I have updated my code to delete cached token before authorization but problem still persists.

Have you tried adding the playlist-modify-private and the playlist-read-private scopes?
